# Powershell to reformat the file content

Tags: powershell

I have a script which gets content from one file and checks for its ip.  Then that is added to some other text file.

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$hlist1 = Get-Content -Path "C:\Timezone\Update\host.txt"
$hiplist = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$hlist2 = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
ForEach ($h in $hlist1)
{
 $hip = Resolve-DnsName $h
 $hiplist.Add($hip)
}
 $hiplist | Out-File "C:\Timezone\Update\hiplist.txt"
```

The file which is getting created is as shown below:

```
             ----                         ----   ---   -------    --------
        WIN-JB2A2FS84MQ.domain.com        A      1200  Answer     10.3.0.4
                                                                   8       
        WIN-QP0BH4SD2H9.domain.com        A      1200  Answer     10.3.1.1
                                                                   9
```

I need to:

1. get rid of the first -------- lines.
2. get the entire ip in the same line (10.3.0.10)

Have tried Format-Table -Autosize, then Select -Skip 1 etc, but no luck.

How can this be achieved.? Please note that the code works fine as expected when it is ran manually, but throws this issue when executed using task scheduler.

**Edit Based on Matt's answer**

Now the text file contains:

```
"Address","IPAddress","QueryType","IP4Address","Name","Type","CharacterSet","Section","DataLength","TTL"
"10.3.0.48","10.3.0.48","A","10.3.0.48","WIN-JB2A2FS84MQ.domain.com","A","Unicode","Answer","4","1200"
"10.3.1.19","10.3.1.19","A","10.3.1.19","WIN-QP0BH4SD2H9.domain.com","A","Unicode","Answer","4","1200"
```

**Peter-sal's reply output:**

```
Name                            Type   TTL   Section    IPAddress                                
----                            ----   ---   -------    ---------                                
WIN-JB2A2FS84MQ.domain.com        A      1200  Answer     10.3.0.48
WIN-QP0BH4SD2H9.domain.com        A      1200  Answer     10.3.1.19
```

But again on top of Name there's one space. I need to delete everything present before WIN-JB2.....

Comment: This might be an issue with how arraylists are converted to strings for output. My guess is that is your issue. Resolving it would be a matter using a different export method or use custom object. `Out-File` will try and cast it to string inorder to output... this is what you are seeing. Any reason you are using an arraylist?

Comment: @Matt: Not exactly. And the weird thing is that the same code works as expected when it ran manually. When I trigger the powershell code using task scheduler I am getting this type of issue.

Comment: `Resolve-DnsName` returns objects so casting them to string can get weird. I don't have a  system with this cmdlet available so I personally cannot test.

Comment: That is an important distinction that would be worth adding to the question.

Comment: @Matt: Question edited. Can you please help me on this.?

Comment: `Out-File -Width 200`

Comment: @PetSerAl You always drop in with little fixes like that. Like the Littlest Hobo of coding.

Comment: @PetSerAl: Please see the edited question.

Comment: @PetSerAl:Same result.. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot test perfectly but I would like to come back to an earlier comment of mine. `Resolve-DNSName` returns objects so their output is better destined for something object aware. `Export-CSV` should be preferable here.

```
$hlist1 = Get-Content -Path "C:\Timezone\Update\host.txt"
$hlist1 | ForEach-Object{Resolve-DnsName $_} | 
    Export-Csv "C:\Timezone\Update\hiplist.txt" -NoTypeInformation
```

I normally don't like this but if you prefer you should be able to use the `Format-table` output now. This seems to be more inline with what you are looking for.

```
$hlist1 = Get-Content -Path "C:\Timezone\Update\host.txt"
$hlist1 | ForEach-Object{Resolve-DnsName $_} | 
    Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Select-Object -Skip 1 |
    Out-File "C:\Timezone\Update\hiplist.txt" -Width 200
```

Perhaps you prefer that output. The header should be removed now as well as a blank line in the beginning.

That creates some white-space before and after the output. Simple solution is to wrap that up in a `Trim()`

```
$hlist1 = Get-Content -Path "C:\Timezone\Update\host.txt"
$results = ($hlist1 | ForEach-Object{Resolve-DnsName $_} |
    Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | 
    Out-string).Trim()`
$results | Out-File "C:\Timezone\Update\hiplist.txt" -Width 200`
```

Comment: @Question edited with the current output. Please see. Now its a mess.

Comment: Now it's a CSV. Comma Separated Value. Will look nice in Excel though.

Comment: @Deadly-Bagel: If possible, I want it in the way I mentioned in the post.

Comment: Again, not an expected output.. :(

Comment: @serverstackqns See my recent edit and look at PetSerAl's comment about `-width`. Your text is wrapping

Comment: @serverstackqns Look at my last update again. Changed the code. Coincidentally coincided with what PetSerAl is trying to say.

Comment: @Matt: Tried your 2nd code. Now I am getting a blank file with an error out-lineoutput : Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in line $hlist1 | ForEach-Object{Resolve-DnsName $_} |

Comment: @serverstackqns I just checked that code on a 8.1 Pro set...... let me double check. There is a couple of extra lines in there but I just ran the code in my second block just fine and got close to the output you desire.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91485/discussion-between-matt-and-serverstackqns).